# Haskell function use show and return Integer

Tags: haskell, io, show

I am troubleshooting with this a long time.

```
asInt_either2 ::  String -> Int
asInt_either2 str
    | null str = 0
    | (head str) == '-' = -1 * asInt_either2 (tail str)
    | isNumber (head str)  = foldl' nasob 0 str
    | otherwise  = error ("Not a Number: '" ++ [(head str)] ++ "'")
    where nasob x y = x*10 + (my_digit y)
        my_digit y
           | isNumber y = digitToInt y
           | otherwise = show ("Not a Number: '" ++ [y] ++ "'")
```

This simply should convert String to Integer, but If it finds not Number character it will print "Not a Number : 'a' " (for example)

I try to get it work but I still get error.
I know, there exist better solutions for this,but this is exercise for me and I want to try it this way, if it is possible.

I am getting error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Int’                                          
  Expected type: Int                   
    Actual type: String                
• In the expression: show ("Not a Number: '" ++ [y] ++ "'")                        
  In an equation for ‘my_digit’:       
      my_digit y 
        | isNumber y = digitToInt y    
        | otherwise = show ("Not a Number: '" ++ [y] ++ "'")                       
  In an equation for ‘asInt_either2’:  
      asInt_either2 str                
        | null str = 0                 
        | (head str) == '-' = - 1 * asInt_either2 (tail str)                       
        | isNumber (head str) = foldl' nasob 0 str                                 
        | otherwise = error ("Not a Number: '" ++ [(head str)] ++ "'")             
        where    
            nasob x y = x * 10 + (my_digit y)                                      
            my_digit y                 
              | isNumber y = digitToInt y                                          
              | otherwise = show ("Not a Number: '" ++ [y] ++ "'")
```

### Update:

Rewrite show to error function solve the problems.

But I am trying to solve this exercise:
"The  function uses error , so its callers cannot handle errors. Rewrite
the function to fix this problem"

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`show` doesn't print anything.  It's just a function to convert something into a `String`

`my_digit` should be an `Int` but `| otherwise = show ("Not a Number: '" ++ [y] ++ "'")` returns a string.  Did you maybe mean to use `error` instead of `show`?

```
        my_digit y                 
          | isNumber y = digitToInt y                                          
          | otherwise = error ("Not a Number: '" ++ [y] ++ "'")
```

This will cause the program to fail and print your error message when it encounters a non-digit character.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I want to print it to output.
For exmaple to use print or putStrLn.

Comment: @lukaskiss Does my solution (using error) work for you then, or were you looking for something else?

Comment: Yes it works :)
But I am trying to solve this Exercise:
"The  function uses error , so its callers cannot handle errors. Rewrite
the function to fix this problem"

Comment: @lukaskiss Look into the Maybe data type. If it's not a number, return Nothing, else return Just the number. Alternatively, you can use Either to provide error strings like you have been doing before.

Comment: @lukaskiss that would require some more fundamental changes.  Instead of your function being `String -> Int` you might use `String -> Maybe Int` or if you need the error message `String -> Either String Int`

Comment: Thank for you answer, I will try to remake it to Maybe option.
By the way, how use print function inside of function ?

Comment: @lukaskiss You can't print things out in a pure function, you have to either make it an IO function, use unsafe ways like unsafePerformIO, or use something like the writer monad to lazily print results as they execute. Generally the best way is to leave it a pure function and return the results you need to print

Comment: @lukaskiss Until you become an Haskell expert, never use `unsafePerformIO`. Just pretend it does not exist -- it's called unsafe for a reason. If you really must print within that function, read about the IO monad and how to use that. I think it's better if you do not print anything, and keep the function pure.